# Why am I getting this TypeError in unittest?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Here is my test.py:

```
import unittest
import sys 
import warnings
import json

sys.path.append('..')
import app

class ApiTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setup(self):
        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=ResourceWarning)
        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

    def get_request(self, api_name, args):
        client = app.app.test_client(self)
        return client.get(f"/{api_name}", query_string=args)
    
    def test_population(self, country, continent):
        response = self.get_request("get_info", {"country":country, "continent":continent})
        return json.loads(response.data)
    
    def test_countries(self):
        countries = ["france", "germany", "spain"]
        for c in countries:
            data = self.test_population(c, "europe")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

and I keep getting the following error when running the file:

```
TypeError: test_population() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'country' and 'continent'
```

the API contacted simply returns a population integer.

Comment: Can you please show the complete error traceback?

Comment: Because you've named the function `test_population` your test runner is going to try to run it as a test. It won't know to call it with the proper arguments. If this function doesn't represent a unit test, you should rename it.

Comment: @Mark Ah I didn't know that - thank you

Comment: Another point. Your tests are not really tests. You dont compare what you actually get with the expected value.

Comment: @balderman I know, I only submitted a heavily edited and minimised version of what I actually have

Answer (score 0):

The required change is

```
def test_population(self):
    response = self.get_request("get_info", {"country":"Germany", "continent":"Europe"})
    return json.loads(response.data)
```

Now the unit-test framework will be able to activate the test method

Comment: This seems like it will be a problem when they call `self.test_population(c, "europe")` as they do in the code presented. This function doesn't seem like a test to me, but rather a util function meant to be called by the user's code (although none are making assertions, so it's a little weird).